# How I can generate a grahical representation at what subnet each resource is located and has access in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, network-monitoring

In my infrastructure I have multiple subnets. I want to have a better picture of what is located and where therefore I want to have some sort of UI that maps each instance into a gui such as:

[image: Reference Image]

Is there a way to do this. I need to have a complete picture of my AWS infrastructure of what resource is located where.

What I want is to have a complete picture of my VPCs and the resources on each one on an undocumented Infrastructure.